Ubuntu update 24.04.1 LTS and I can't access VPN
After updating to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and I can't access VPN, the following information appears:
POST https://vpn.semfio.usp.br/
Trying to connect to server 200.144.255.251:443
Connected to 200.144.255.251:443
SSL negotiation with vpn.semfio.usp.br
SSL connection failure: A packet with illegal or unsupported version was received.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to vpn.semfio.usp.br

What should I do? Before the update it was working normally.

Have you tried asking the VPN company if they support Ubuntu 24.04?

One advice; reinstall the packages for VPN with sudo apt install --reinstall <list_of_packages> ; probably for some reason, the upgrade went wrong and possibly, some packages are missing and were removed during the upgrade. The upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.1 is clearly bugged.

Diana, did you find a solution?
